# I am writing a cover letter and I have faced a few grammar doubts

Tags: grammar

firstly I would like to say that is not a question about what to include in a cover letter etc. as I have done extensive research on that and I know this space is solely for English language questions.

I feel some of the questions I will ask or trying to split hairs, but at the end of the day English is not my first language and I deeply appreciate and value advice on improving.

> I am passionate about OR I am passionate in?

I think both will work.

If I want to refer to the 2022 summer semester (I live in the USA and my university follows the usual semester system), would I use

> This summer OR last summer?

I want to refer to my junior and senior years, not sure if it is year or years:

> During my junior and senior years or during my junior and senior year?

Thank you all again for the guidance!

Comment: Why are you unsure about which tag to use besides "grammar"? If you [search ELL's tags](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags), I'm sure you'll find some that would work. (Your first question involves "prepositions", for example.)

Comment: By the way, you should also 1) explain what research you've already done, 2) provide adequate context (especially for your second example here), and 3) focus on only one topic per question.

Comment: Sadly this question falls under the heading "Questions asking for someone to find and correct errors or improve the phrasing are considered requests for proofreading and are off-topic. "

Comment: Also, on a resume (CV)/cover letter, being "passionate" could be considered a trite 
cliché and overblown.